# `RegionWithin` returns incomprehensible result

Tags: bugs, regions

I try to get the condition "ball inside cube"

```
RegionWithin[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}], Ball[{x, y, z}, r]]
```

but Mathematica v12.2 gives error `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {0,0,0}<={-r+x,r+x} cannot be combined.` and returns

```
{-r + y, r + y} && {a, b, c} && {-r + x, r + x} && {0, 0, 0}
```

What's wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know the answer to why it does not work (it should), but here is a workaround.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
r1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]
r2 = ImplicitRegion[
   0 < (x - v1)^2 + (y - v2)^2 + (z - v3)^2 <= r^2, {x, y, z}];

RegionQ /@ {r1, r2}

RegionWithin[r1, r2] // Simplify

(v3 >= 0 && a > v1 && b >= v2 && c >= v3 && v1 >= 0 && 
   a^2 + v1^2 >= r^2 + 2 a v1 && v2 >= 0 && 
   b^2 + v2^2 >= r^2 + 2 b v2 && c^2 + v3^2 >= r^2 + 2 c v3 && a > 0 &&
    b > 0 && c > 0 && r^2 <= v1^2 && r^2 <= v2^2 && r^2 <= v3^2) || 
 r == 0
```

Comment: Thanks! In the `r2=ImplicitRegion[...]` definition the part `0<` is important and makes the difference compared to `r2=Ball[{v1,v2,v3},r]` which doesn't work. No idea why!

Comment: Initially I tried with  `<=` then I realized that the ball would cease to exist and perhaps the system would go from a 3D object to a point instead; but I am not sure. The habitual use of `x,y,z` as axes prevented me from using these as the center of the sphere; but I am sure there is a way around it.

Answer (score 7):

- A bug.
- When we replace `Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]` with `Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{a, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {0, 0, c}}]`, it work.

```
conditions=RegionWithin[
 Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{a, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {0, 0, c}}], 
 Ball[{x, y, z}, r]]
```

[image]

- Simplify the result if we assume that `a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0`.

```
Simplify[conditions, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
```

> `x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && a >= x && b >= y && c >= z &&  r^2 <= x^2 && a^2 + x^2 >= r^2 + 2 a x && r^2 <= y^2 &&  b^2 + y^2 >= r^2 + 2 b y && r^2 <= z^2 && c^2 + z^2 >= r^2 + 2 c z`

- 

```
RegionEqual[
 Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{a, 0, 0}, {0, b, 0}, {0, 0, c}}], 
 Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]]
```

> `True`.

Comment: Thanks! Surprising, Mathematica is only able to solve  the more complicated case `Parallelepiped`